# JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore causes infinite loop for EF models

Tags: c#, ios, json, entity-framework

I have an EF, database first, set of models that have relationships between themselves as dictated by the DB's foreign keys. When I try to return that object graph from Web API I have problems. I have read countless posts on this site to try to fix my original issue of

> Self referencing loop detected for property 'Merchant' with type 'MP.Models.Merchant'. Path 'tickets[0].customer.Merchant.Addresses[0]'.

I know that each Address object has a Merchant property that points back to the Merchant and causes the loop.

I have read that `RefenceLoopHandling.Ignore` is supposed to just ignore the references, after the initial one, and not serialize them and all should work, but what happens when I do that is I get an infinite loop and my worker process grows to the size of my physical memory and I have to kill it.

Using `PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` instead of the `.Ignore` does work to return all the objects and their references, but I have an iOS app that I assume will not be able to convert that JSON because I have read that you need to deserialize with json.net for this to work.

I don't want to hard code any `jsonIgnore` attributes on the property collections because there are times when I need that collection populated, like when I am returning a list of addresses and I want their Merchant property populated.

1. Why isn't `.Ignore` working as all the other posts on the topic
   suggest?
2. If I have to stick with `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, how would the iOS app be able to use this JSON format?

Comment: Are you lazy loading navigation properties or eager loading? I have given up lazily loading them due to all the self referencing loop problems

Comment: No, Lazy loading is turned off

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a many-to-many relationship in your model?

I found out (the hard way) that `RefenceLoopHandling.Ignore` will still get into an infinite loop if you have a many-to-many relationship between two entities and both entities have `ICollection` navigation properties to each other.

How to solve it?  I put `[JsonIgnore]` on one of those navigation properties.  A hack, but works.

Comment: This is the only answer I have found which explains why `ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore` can still throw exceptions, thank you

Comment: Maybe the latest EF version (or EF7?) should solve it... or open a bug ticket.  There should be times when you can't put `JsonIgnore` on one of the collection properties...

Comment: additional to @Novastorm 's answer:  there are two JsonIgnores:  System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore and  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnore, be sure to use to right one.

Comment: @StephenChung no, it is still there.